# Ограничение на решение ДУ с использованием решателя ode45

Tags: события, matlab

Добрый вечер.

Опишу свою проблему: имеется система ОДУ, среди которой есть два уравнения, отвечающие за величину угла и угловой скорости. Величина угла (как решение ДУ) не должно превышать какой-то заданной величины; когда угол по модулю достигает такого значения, скорость обнуляется. В идейном плане это, например, отклонение маятника - в старинных часах такие есть, к примеру.
Так вот, я использую функцию событий, чтобы отлавливать предельные значения угла. По типу задачи ballode, интегрирование приостанавливается и начинается вновь с обновленными начальными данными. Т.е. я обнуляю решение уравнения, отвечающего за скорость и еще раз ограничиваю решение величины угла. В этом случае при отладке величина угла не вылезает из предельного значения - никуда не отклоняется. Если только обнулять скорость, величина угла превышает порог.
На плюсах все необходимое реализовано, и тут я думаю, что манипуляции я провожу конкретно на шагах интегрирования, т.е. нет конфликта с особенностями метода интегрирования. В матлабе подобным образом (с заданным шагом интегрирования) я пробовала, однако это многократно увеличивает время расчета (где-то полчаса).

Буду рада хоть каким-то мыслям/идеям.